# Sencha touch How to combine filters

Tags: forms, filter, extjs

i have 6 different filters on a single list and i want to render the app on mobile screen
to save the toolbar space I want to combine all that filters.

the problem is, when I combine these filters in a single form panel these filters dose not work
can you please guide me on how to combine them,  should I combine these filters in overlay panel rather than formPanel

following is the code for filters.js

kiva.views.LoanFilter = Ext.extend(Ext.form.FormPanel, {
      ui: 'green',
      cls: 'x-toolbar-dark',
      baseCls: 'x-toolbar',

```
  initComponent: function() {
      this.addEvents('filter');
      this.enableBubble('filter');
      var form;
      var showForm = function(btn, event) {
          form = new Ext.form.FormPanel(formBase);
          form.showBy(btn);
          form.show();
      };

      Ext.apply(this, {
          defaults: {
              listeners: {
                  change: this.onFieldChange,
                  scope: this
              }
          },

          layout: {
              type: 'hbox',
              align: 'center'
          },

          items: [
              {
                  xtype: 'button',
                  iconCls:'info',
                  title:'info',
                  iconMask:true,
                  ui:'plain',
              },{
                  xtype: 'spacer'
              },/*{
                  xtype: 'selectfield',
                  name: 'search',
                  prependText: 'Search:',
                  options: [
                      {text: 'Location',  value: 'location'},
                      {text: 'Theme',     value: 'theme'},
                  ]
              },*/{
                  xtype: 'searchfield',
                  name: 'q',
                  placeholder: 'Search',
                  value: 'Destination or ID',
                  listeners : {
                      change: this.onFieldChange,
                      keyup: function(field, e) {
                          var key = e.browserEvent.keyCode;
                          // blur field when user presses enter/search which will trigger a change if necessary.
                          if (key === 13) {
                              field.blur();
                          }
                      },
                      scope : this
                  }
              },{
                xtype: 'selectfield',
                name : 'sort_by',
                prependText: 'sort_by:',
                ui:'button',
                cls:'sortbox',
                options: [
                    {text: 'Sort By',          value: ''},
                    {text: 'Newest',        value: 'modified'},
                    {text: 'Sleeps',        value: 'sleep_max'},
                    {text: 'Sleeps Desc',   value: 'sleep_max DESC'},
                    {text: 'Bedrooms',      value: 'bedroom'},
                    {text: 'Bedrooms Desc', value: 'bedroom DESC'},
                   // {text: 'Rates',         value: 'rates'},
                ]
             },{
                xtype: 'button',
                text: 'Filters',
                handler: showForm
            }
          ]
      });

      kiva.views.LoanFilter.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments);


      //for filters form

      var formBase = {
          scroll: 'vertical',
          //url   :
          standardSubmit : true,
          items: [{
                  xtype: 'fieldset',
                  title: 'Filters',
                  instructions: 'Please enter the information above.',
                  defaults: {
                      //required: true,
                      labelAlign: 'left',
                      labelWidth: '30%'
                  },
                  items: [

                      {
                          xtype: 'spinnerfield',
                          name : 'sleep_max',
                          label: 'Sleeps',
                          minValue: 0,
                          maxValue:10
                      },{
                          xtype: 'spinnerfield',
                          name : 'bedroom',
                          label: 'Bedrooms',
                          minValue: 0,
                          maxValue:10
                      },{
                          xtype: 'spinnerfield',
                          name : 'rates',
                          label: 'Rates',
                          minValue: 50,
                          maxValue:5000,
                          incrementValue: 100,
                          cycle: false
                      },/*{
                          xtype: 'datepickerfield',
                          name : 'checkIn',
                          label: 'Check In',
                          destroyPickerOnHide: true,

                      },{
                          xtype: 'datepickerfield',
                          name : 'checkOut',
                          label: 'Check Out',
                          destroyPickerOnHide: true,
                      },*/{
                          xtype: 'selectfield',
                          name : 'themes',
                          label: 'Themes',
                          options: [
                              {text: 'Themes',    value: ''},
                              {text: 'Skiing',    value: 'skiing'},
                              {text: 'Golf',      value: 'golf'},
                              {text: 'Beaches',   value: 'beaches'},
                              {text: 'Adventure', value: 'adventure'},
                              {text: 'Family',    value: 'family'},
                              {text: 'Fishing',   value: 'fishing'},
                              {text: 'Boating',   value: 'boating'},
                              {text: 'Historic',  value: 'historic'},
                              {text: 'Biking',    value: 'biking'},
                          ]
                      },/*{
                          xtype: 'hiddenfield',
                          name : 'secret',
                          value: 'false'
                  },*/]
          }],
          listeners : {
              submit : function(form, result){
                  console.log('success', Ext.toArray(arguments));
                  console.log(form);
                  console.log(result);
                  form.hide();
                 // Ext.Msg.alert('Sent!','Your message has been sent.', form.hide());
              },
              exception : function(form, result){
                  console.log('failure', Ext.toArray(arguments));
                  form.hide();
                 // Ext.Msg.alert('Sent!','Your message has been sent.', form.hide());
              }
          },

          dockedItems: [
              {
                  xtype: 'toolbar',
                  dock: 'bottom',
                  items: [
                      {
                          text: 'Cancel',
                          handler: function() {
                              form.hide();
                          }
                      },
                      {xtype: 'spacer'},
                      {
                          text: 'Reset',
                          handler: function() {
                              form.reset();
                          }
                      },
                      {
                          text: 'Apply',
                          ui: 'confirm',
                          handler: function() {
                              form.submit({
                                  waitMsg : {message:'Submitting', cls : 'demos-loading'}
                              });
                          }
                      }
                  ]
              }
          ]
      };

      if (Ext.is.Phone) {
          formBase.fullscreen = true;
      } else {
          Ext.apply(formBase, {
              autoRender: true,
              floating: true,
              modal: true,
              centered: false,
              hideOnMaskTap: false,
              height: 300,
              width: 420,
          });
      }

  },

  /**
   * This is called whenever any of the fields in the form are changed. It simply collects all of the
   * values of the fields and fires the custom 'filter' event.
   */
  onFieldChange : function(comp, value) {
  //console.log(comp);  console.log(value);

      this.fireEvent('filter', this.getValues(), this);
  }
```

});

Ext.reg('loanFilter', kiva.views.LoanFilter);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its not clear what do you mean under "filters doesn't work".
Form with filter is not showing, then probably you need to set `floating: true` for the form as it is a panel and need to be floated if you want to show popup. http://docs.sencha.com/touch/1-1/#!/api/Ext.lib.Component-cfg-floating

Your form is not a part of `LoanFilter` form (why it is a form?), so method onFieldChange will not be triggered while you changing fields inside `form`. You need to move event listener to `formBase`

```
var formBase = {
defaults: {
              listeners: {
                  change: this.onFieldChange,
                  scope: this
              }
          },
...
```

Comment: Hey Paul,

Thanks for reply man.

Form panel with filters renders properly without any JS errors, but the changes in filters doesn't gets applied to list.
i tried to set the listener for Apply button and also to individual filters. also i tried to set defaults in formbase as suggested

filters outside formbase like search box and sorting does works correctly.

can you please suggest any other idea to hide all these filters, i cant show them all on single toolbar...